# Selenium. IEDriverServer.exe does not exist?

Tags: selenium

I get an error:

**The file Capabilities [BrowserName=, IsJavaScriptEnabled=False, Platform=Any, Version=]\IEDriverServer.exe does not exist. The driver can be downloaded at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list`**

What must I do to solve this error because really I can't find information ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you're building the Selenium project from sources, or are using the .NET bindings and have set a specific option in the `InternetExplorerOptions` class, you shouldn't be seeing this message. The current source code is volatile in this particular area, as the project is currently implementing the usage of a standalone executable server for the IE driver, similar to what happens currently for the Chrome driver. If you **are** building from source, or are interested in using this new functionality, you should download the standalone IE driver server executable from the URL specified in the exception's message.

Answer (score 0):

Download the IEDriver.exe for the given URL

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list

Assuming the exe file is saved in E:\IEdriver.exe.

In Selenium you have to set the property of IEDriver, since Selenium has only firefox driver with it.

Set the system property and then invoke the IEDriver.

```
WebDriver driver;

System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "E:\\IEdriver.exe");

//Selenium will not support single slash, so we are providing double slash in path.

driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

// By this it will call the IEDriver and execute
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An example to share:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get("www.google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("abc");
        driver.close();

}
```

}